# Como fazer um parse de uma lista de objetos para outra?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tenho uma lista de tarefas armazenada em um objeto `items`, quero fazer um parse desta lista de modo que, tudo que esteja com status **aberto** seja armazenado na variável `openTasks` e tudo que esteja com status **concluído** seja armazenando em `completedTasks`.

Cheguei a rabiscar algo mas não deu muito certo. Veja:

```
export class AllTasksPage {

  openTasks;
  completedTasks;

  items = [
    {'title': 'Entregar relatório', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'aberta'},
    {'title': 'Fazer compras', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'aberta'},
    {'title': 'Concluir trabalho da faculdade', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'concluida'},
    {'title': 'Ligar para cliente', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'concluida'},
    {'title': 'Revisar trabalho', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'aberta'},
    {'title': 'Falar com chefe', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'concluida'},
    {'title': 'Estudar apra prova', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'aberta'},
    {'title': 'Buscar roupa na lavanderia', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'aberta'},
    {'title': 'Limpar a casa', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'aberta'},
    {'title': 'Estudar para apresentação', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'aberta'},
    {'title': 'Assistir filme xpto', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'aberta'},
    {'title': 'Colocar a roupa para lavar', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'aberta'}
  ];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {

    for (let item of this.items) {
      if (item.status == 'aberta') {
        this.openTasks.concat(item);
      }
    }
  }
```

Resumindo: quero que `openTasks` e `comletedTasks` tenham a mesma estrutura existente em `items`, porém, os dados irão mudar com base no status das tarefas.

Comment: Pode usar o `filter` para passar dados de um array pro outro, o primeiro vai ficar apenas com os `open` e o outro com os `completed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar o [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) para filtrar itens de um array.

```js
const items = [
  {'title': 'Entregar relatório', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'aberta'},
  {'title': 'Fazer compras', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'aberta'},
  {'title': 'Concluir trabalho da faculdade', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'concluida'},
  {'title': 'Ligar para cliente', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'concluida'},
  {'title': 'Revisar trabalho', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'aberta'},
  {'title': 'Falar com chefe', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'concluida'},
  {'title': 'Estudar apra prova', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'aberta'},
  {'title': 'Buscar roupa na lavanderia', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'aberta'},
  {'title': 'Limpar a casa', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'aberta'},
  {'title': 'Estudar para apresentação', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'aberta'},
  {'title': 'Assistir filme xpto', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'aberta'},
  {'title': 'Colocar a roupa para lavar', 'note': '', 'image': '', 'status': 'aberta'}
];

const filterByStatus = (status) => {
  return items.filter((item) => item.status === status);
};

const onlyOpened = filterByStatus("aberta");
const onlyCompleted = filterByStatus("concluida");

console.log("Only opened", onlyOpened);
console.log("Only completed", onlyCompleted);
```

O método não tem efeitos colaterais, e retorna um novo array filtrado.

Comment: Uma outra possibilidade é quando verificar o status e não for "aberta" adicionar em `onlyCompleted`, se for "concluida" apenas retorna `true` assim não é necessário percorrer o mesmo array duas vezes seguidas